# bootstrap 4 beta 2 back-to-top does not work

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a back-to-top link in my navbar which work properly in bootstrap 3.3.7 but not in bootstrap 4 beta 2

back-to-top js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var offset = 100;
   var duration = 800;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        $('#back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
    } else {
        $('#back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
    }
});

// scroll body to 0px on click
$('#back-to-top').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#back-to-top').tooltip('hide');
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, duration);
    return false;
});

$('#back-to-top').tooltip('show');
});
```

html code in the web application

```
  <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".fixed-top">

        <div id="main-navbar" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-custom navbar-dark" role="navigation" >


                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main-collapse">

                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>Menu
                        <i class="navbar-icon fa fa-bars icon"></i> 
                         <!--<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>-->

                    </button>

                    <a href="#" id="menu-toggler" class="navbar-brand"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand page-scroll" id="back-to-top">Funeral Aftercare Service</a>

                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-main-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="d-none"><a href="#page-top"></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="<?php echo $index; ?>" href="index.php">
                                <span class="fa fa-home"></span> Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="<?php echo $about; ?>" href="about_us.php">About Us</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="<?php echo $contact; ?>" href="contact_info.php">Contact Info</a></li>

                    </ul>...
```

I notice that in the bootstrap 3, the jquery file (jquery-3.2.1.min.js) load more functions in for my back-to-top link while in bootstrap 4 less.

bootstrap 4 load only the **first 2** in inspect view while bootstrap 3 load all of them

**click** -back-to-top.js (jQuery)

**click** - jquery-3.2.1.min.js (Bubbling DOM2)

focusin - jquery-3.2.1.min.js (jQuery)

focusout - jquery-3.2.1.min.js (jQuery)

mouseout - jquery-3.2.1.min.js (jQuery)

mouseout - jquery-3.2.1.min.js (Bubbling DOM2)

mouseover - jquery-3.2.1.min.js (jQuery)

mouseover - jquery-3.2.1.min.js (Bubbling DOM2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on bootstrap 4 documentation:
“If you’re using our compiled JavaScript, don’t forget to include CDN versions of jQuery and Popper.js before it.”

Your code seems correct, you need to load popper.js after jquery and before bootstrap 4.

Comment: It seems that was it, I put popper.js after bootstrap 4 js and that why the animation did not work.

Comment: @JohnLaimuin Do you mean scroll animation? It works for me. It's correct.